# Terminal output is mixed up by using two commands in parallel - how to avoid this?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'd like to write a bash script for ripping a huge dvd collection using dvdbackup. Using four dvd-drives in parallel, the terminal output of dvdbackup is mixed up.

```
dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/sr0 -o /home/xxxx/vids/ &
dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/sr1 -o /home/xxxx/vids/
```

I need the terminal output to control possible errors. How can I control the output?
It's a bit hard for me to find a matching searchterm for google regarding this problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not knowing what `dvdbackup` would write to the terminal: are you concerned with "regular" output messages mixing up with error messahes or with errors from different instances of `dvdbackup` mixing up with each other?

Comment: i am concerned with mixed up messages from different instances of dvdbackup; the terminal output is not readable, if four instances are running and generate output in one terminal.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "How can I control the output?"? What would you like to see? Tagged messages (to tell them apart while still on one single terminal)? Messages redirected somewhere else (e.g. to distinct files)?

Comment: Would like to see tagged messages (to tell them apart while still on one single terminal).

Answer (score 3):

Using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) you can do:

```
parallel --line-buffer --tag 'dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/{1} -o /home/xxxx/vids/' ::: sr0 sr1
```

From its manual:

> --tag
>     Tag lines with arguments. Each output line will be prepended with the arguments and TAB (\t).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The programs are running in parallel, so they are both writing to the terminal at the same time. What you can do is capture the standard error of each instance into a separate file:

```
dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/sr0 -o /home/xxxx/vids/ 2>log1 &
dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/sr1 -o /home/xxxx/vids/ 2>log2
```

You will then have the errors/progress reports etc of the first `dvdbackup` command in `log1` and those of the second in `log2`.

---

Alternatively, if you just want to add a tag to their error output, you could do:

```
dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/sr0 -o vids/ 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | 
    sed 's/^/Process A /' &  
dvdbackup -Mv --progress --error=a -i /dev/sr1 -o vids/ 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | 
    sed 's/^/Process B /'
```

That will add the string `Process A` to the beginning of each line printed to stderr by the first process and `Process B` to the beginning of each line printed to the stderr of the second.

For example:

```
$ seq 1 5 | sed 's/^/process A /' & seq 1 5 | sed 's/^/process B /'
[1] 1549053
process A 1
process A 2
process A 3
process A 4
process A 5
process B 1
process B 2
process B 3
process B 4
process B 5
[1]+  Done                    seq 1 5 | sed 's/^/process A /'
```